How do I adjust Chrome settings with TBox Start Program Arguments
I would like to use TBox Start Program for opening Chrome browser with already adjusted settings. For example, by default set not to show downloaded documents after download is finished.
I found some argument for module TBox Start Program for e.g. opening in Incognito mode, etc., but I cannot find any list of potentially usable arguments for Chrome in general.
Does anybody here have experience with Tosca automation of Chrome in general. Can you recommend me some source of knowledge regarding this topic.

I tried this argument, but it is not working.
